# How can I reset the dropdown menu on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

How can I reset the dropdown menu on button click?

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="Software" ng-options="o as o for o in Softwares" id="softId" onChange="onSelectFilter()">
    <option value=''>--- Software ---</option>
</select>
<button id="resetDd" class="btn btn-default">GO</button>
```

```js
app.controller('TechCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.Softwares = [ "Word", "Excel", "PowerPoint", "Publisher", "Access", "Paint", "Movie maker" ];
});
```

I want to do this with out refreshing the page. How can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried `$scope.Software = null`?https://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/z1pLcqL4/2/

Comment: no, i will try and replay to you

Answer (score 1):

> *The ngModel directive binds an input,select, textarea (or custom form control) to a property on the scope using NgModelController, which is created and exposed by this directive.*[[Ref](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel)]

To reset the value of the `select input`, reset the value of the model `Software`. The initial value of the `select` is `''` hence to reset it, one needs to set the `scope` variable to `''`

Try this:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('TechCtrl', TechCtrl);

function TechCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.Softwares = ["Word", "Excel", "PowerPoint", "Publisher", "Access", "Paint", "Movie maker"];
  $scope.reset = function() {
    $scope.Software = '';
  }
  $scope.onSelectFilter = function() {

  };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="TechCtrl">
    <select class="form-control" ng-model="Software" ng-options="o as o for o in Softwares" id="softId" ng-change="onSelectFilter()">
      <option value=''>--- Software ---</option>
    </select>
    <button id="resetDd" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="reset()">RESET</button>

  </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/GkarV/897/)

Comment: just asking: how can ng-model can be used in a plural form in angular? - I want to  learn angular and it wold help me. In this example the` ng-model is `Software` but in controller you use it like `$scope.Softwares` - can u give me a link or sth to read about?

Comment: In `ng-repeat`, `s in softwares` would create different scope of each `s`, they will not collide with each other. I hope I read you right..[[Ref](https://scotch.io/tutorials/building-dynamic-angular-forms-with-ngrepeat-and-ngform)]

Comment: Happy to help! Kindly [accept and up-vote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow) the best solution which has solved the purpose :) __Happy coding!__

Answer (score 0):

Try setting value of `Software` to `null`

```
<button id="resetDd" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="Software = null">GO</button>
```